# How to git log --graph showing only branch heads?

Tags: git

How can I use `git log --graph` to include only commits that are current branch heads?

eg.

```
$ git log --graph --all --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(auto)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

gives:

```
*   fa3d2f92d - (HEAD -> feat/pullupstream) Merge remote-tracking branch 'foundation/master' into feat/pullupstream (48 minutes ago) <me>
|\  
* | a12984977 - (myuser/feat/chainconfig-equivalence-test, mycompany/feat/chainconfig-equivalence-test, feat/istanbul-featureblocks, feat/chainconfig-equivalence-test) Makefile: add test-multigeth command (3 hours ago) <Jeff>
* | 7c471933a - tests: add equivalence-proof tests for fork feature configs (3 hours ago) <Jeff>
* | 47189785b - params: remove and comment CheckConfigForkOrder (3 hours ago) <Jeff>
* | 87d575b8f - params: remove unused IsEIP158 method (3 hours ago) <Jeff>
* | aaf58e484 - core/vm: fix commented fork names (3 hours ago) <Jeff>
* | 1771de385 - core: prefer EIP161F feat instead of EIP158 (3 hours ago) <Jeff>
* | 30ded24cc - tests: s/IsEIP158/IsEIP161F/ (4 hours ago) <Jeff>
* | 7839340cc - Makefile: add env var to enable args to test cmd (4 hours ago) <Jeff>
* | c398d1231 - (mycompany/feat/verbose-test-logs, feat/verbose-test-logs) build: add test cmd flag -v for verbose logs (4 hours ago) <Jeff>
| | * 488a69b8b - (feat/x-chainspec) consensus/ethash,params: refactor HasECIP1017->IsECIP1017F (78 minutes ago) <Jeff>
| | * 456aa8cc9 - params: add ECIP1017FBlock to satisfy forkid implementation (78 minutes ago) <Jeff>
| | * b945c3902 - core/forkid: test gatherForks func against ETC conf (78 minutes ago) <Jeff>
| | * 3e0527dcb - cmd/utils: refactor datadir from --chain context (78 minutes ago) <Jeff>
| | * 6b1d6b6d5 - cmd/utils: refactor --[chain] -> genesis logic (78 minutes ago) <Jeff>
| | * 54e5272c2 - chainspec,cmd/faucet|geth|utils,eth,mobile,params: refactor NetworkId (78 minutes ago) <Jeff>
| | * aa18677ce - chainspec: init support for Parity/Clique config (78 minutes ago) <Jeff>
| | * e46bcfb8e - cmd/puppeth,+chainspec: move chainspec data structures to own package (78 minutes ago) <Jeff>
| | * 6ec3edff4 - cmd/puppeth: export ChainSpecs and New_ methods (78 minutes ago) <Jeff>
| | *   864e57887 - (multi-geth/master, master) Merge pull request #124 from mycompany/fix/mordor-genesis-timestamp (9 hours ago) <Tang>
| | |\  
| | | * dc17c5d96 - (mycompany/fix/mordor-genesis-timestamp, fix/mordor-genesis-timestamp) core: set mordor genesis block timestamp (2 days ago) <Jeff>
| | |/  
| | | * fde76dc96 - (mycompany.technology.go-technology/feat/makefile-test-cmd-args-ef, feat/makefile-test-cmd-args-ef) Makefile: add env var to enable args to test cmd (2 hours ago) <Jeff>
| | |/  
| |/|   
| | | * b77fa876f - (mycompany.technology.go-technology/feat/verbose-test-logs-ef, feat/verbose-test-logs-ef) build: add test cmd flag -v for verbose logs (2 hours ago) <Jeff>
| | |/  
| |/|   
| * | 738b51ae3 - (foundation/master, foundation/HEAD, mycompany.technology.go-technology/foundation-master, foundation-master) core/vm: fix tracer interface parameter name (#20294) (11 hours ago) <nejsad4>
| * | f03b2db7d - params: finish sentence in comment (#20291) (23 hours ago) <myuser>
| * | 49d1a032d - build: gather info to investigate why builds fail on ARM (#20281) (30 hours ago) <Guillaume>
| * | 765fe446c - whisper/whisperv6: fix staticcheck issues (#20288) (35 hours ago) <Guillaume>
```

But I want only commits with branch refs:

```
*   fa3d2f92d - (HEAD -> feat/pullupstream, gogs/feat/pullupstream) Merge remote-tracking branch 'foundation/master' into feat/pullupstream (49 minutes ago) <me>
|\  
* | a12984977 - (myuser/feat/chainconfig-equivalence-test, mycompany/feat/chainconfig-equivalence-test, feat/istanbul-featureblocks, feat/chainconfig-equivalence-test) Makefile: add test-multigeth command (3 hours ago) <Jeff>
* | c398d1231 - (mycompany/feat/verbose-test-logs, feat/verbose-test-logs) build: add test cmd flag -v for verbose logs (4 hours ago) <Jeff>
| | * 488a69b8b - (feat/x-chainspec) consensus/ethash,params: refactor HasECIP1017->IsECIP1017F (80 minutes ago) <Jeff>
| | *   864e57887 - (multi-geth/master, master) Merge pull request #124 from mycompany/fix/mordor-genesis-timestamp (9 hours ago) <Tang>
| | |\  
| | | * dc17c5d96 - (mycompany/fix/mordor-genesis-timestamp, fix/mordor-genesis-timestamp) core: set mordor genesis block timestamp (2 days ago) <Jeff>
| | |/  
| | | * fde76dc96 - (mycompany.technology.go-technology/feat/makefile-test-cmd-args-ef, feat/makefile-test-cmd-args-ef) Makefile: add env var to enable args to test cmd (2 hours ago) <Jeff>
| | |/  
| |/|   
| | | * b77fa876f - (mycompany.technology.go-technology/feat/verbose-test-logs-ef, feat/verbose-test-logs-ef) build: add test cmd flag -v for verbose logs (2 hours ago) <Jeff>
| | |/  
| |/|   
| * | 738b51ae3 - (foundation/master, foundation/HEAD, mycompany.technology.go-technology/foundation-master, foundation-master) core/vm: fix tracer interface parameter name (#20294) (11 hours ago) <nebojsa94>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [`--simplify-by-decoration`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---simplify-by-decoration) option.

You can also filter the references you keep for dislay using [--decorate-refs / --decorate-refs-exclude](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---decorate-refsltpatterngt) :

```
# will only keep branches (not tags) starting with "feature/" or "bug/" :
git log --oneline --graph --simplify-by-decoration
    --decorate-refs=refs/heads/feature
    --decorate-refs=refs/heads/bug

# will keep all refs and exclude tags starting with "private/" :
git log --oneline --graph --simplify-by-decoration
    --decorate-refs-exclude=refs/tags/private
```

Answer (score 2):

You have even more control on `--decorate-refs` with Git 2.38 (Q3 2022): the namespaces used by "`log --decorate`" from "`refs/`" hierarchy by default has been tightened.

See [commit 992f25d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/992f25d713d8fe02966491bbe6f45fd18e3b8d02), [commit 863a8ae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/863a8ae97b7b5b112b928f2fab8185bb7574e7b3), [commit 3e103ed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e103ed23f2950a111a9ef8480a629d7331dc6ee), [commit 748706d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/748706d71365f419dad94cb7e54a31151c197218), [commit 9215629](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92156291ca82ae4f4ad09fde8181c5f2b7dba6ca), [commit 94d421b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94d421b8afa0dc46fcd03143f10b4f3828b20104), [commit 97e61e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/97e61e0f9cd96f403504ec97cfdf38f238777560), [commit b9342b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9342b3fd6308c351f53075c9c4339913b73451f), [commit 5797b13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5797b13919f8073108e58ab5cea39f4e6bbfa1c9), [commit b004521](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b004521aa6f935fecd1426cab2997f7f8b31dcab), [commit b877e61](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b877e617e6e582553e21055deb272ce3a1354e1a) (05 Aug 2022) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c068a3b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c068a3b8ee40d6e009da33d742d6a87dbaf7f1c6), 29 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`log`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92156291ca82ae4f4ad09fde8181c5f2b7dba6ca): add default decoration filter
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> When a user runs '[`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/92156291ca82ae4f4ad09fde8181c5f2b7dba6ca/Documentation/git-log.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup>, they expect a certain set of helpful decorations.
> This includes:
>
> - The `HEAD` ref
> - Branches (`refs/heads/`)
> - Stashes (`refs/stash`)
> - Tags (`refs/tags/`)
> - Remote branches (`refs/remotes/`)
> - Replace refs (`refs/replace/` or `$GIT_REPLACE_REF_BASE)`
>
> Each of these namespaces was selected due to existing test cases that verify these namespaces appear in the decorations.
> In particular, stashes and replace refs can have custom colors from the `color.decorate.<slot>` config option.
>
> While one test checks for a decoration from `notes`, it only applies to the tip of `refs/notes/commit` (or its configured ref name).
> Notes form their own kind of decoration instead.
>
> There are several tests throughout the codebase that verify that `--decorate-refs`, `--decorate-refs-exclude`, and `log.excludeDecoration` work as designed.
>
> However, there are other refs that are less helpful to show as decoration:
>
> - Prefetch refs (`refs/prefetch/`)
> - Rebase refs (`refs/rebase-merge/` and `refs/rebase-apply/`)
> - Bundle refs (`refs/bundle/`) [!]
>
> [!] The bundle refs are part of a parallel series that bootstraps a repo from a bundle file, storing the bundle's refs into the repo's `refs/bundle/` namespace.
>
> In the case of prefetch refs, [96eaffe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/96eaffebbf3d00a498c28bc689e70d9d94bc9911) ("`maintenance`: set `log.excludeDecoration` during prefetch", 2021-01-19, Git v2.31.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15bf48b9872e9c42015aa6bffcbafa4c680013ff) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30b29f044a2b30f0667eb21559959e03eb1bd04f)) added logic to add `refs/prefetch/` to the `log.excludeDecoration` config option.
>
> Additional feedback pointed out that having such a side-effect can be confusing and perhaps not helpful to users.
> Instead, we should hide these ref namespaces that are being used by Git for internal reasons but are not helpful for the users to see.
>
> The way to provide a seamless user experience without setting the config is to modify the default decoration filters to match our expectation of what refs the user actually wants to see.
>
> In [`builtin/log.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/92156291ca82ae4f4ad09fde8181c5f2b7dba6ca/builtin/log.c), after parsing the `--decorate-refs` and `--decorate-refs-exclude` options from the command-line, call `set_default_decoration_filter()`.
> This method populates the exclusions from `log.excludeDecoration`, then checks if the list of pattern modifications are empty.
> If none are specified, then the default set is restricted to the set of inclusions mentioned earlier (HEAD, branches, etc.).
>
> The 'decoration' value is non-zero when that namespace is associated with a special coloring and fits into the list of "expected" decorations as described above, which makes the implementation of this filter very simple.
>
> Note that the logic in `ref_filter_match()` in [`log-tree.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/92156291ca82ae4f4ad09fde8181c5f2b7dba6ca/log-tree.c) follows this matching pattern:
>
> 1. If there are exclusion patterns and the ref matches one, then ignore the decoration.
> 2. If there are inclusion patterns and the ref matches one, then definitely include the decoration.
> 3. If there are config-based exclusions from log.excludeDecoration and the ref matches one, then ignore the decoration.
>
> With this logic in mind, we need to ensure that we do not populate our new defaults if any of these filters are manually set.
> Specifically, if a user runs
>
> ```
> git -c log.excludeDecoration=HEAD log
> ```
>
> then we expect the HEAD decoration to not appear.
> If we left the default inclusions in the set, then HEAD would match that inclusion before reaching the config-based exclusions.
>
> A potential alternative would be to check the list of default inclusions at the end, after the config-based exclusions.
> This would still create a behavior change for some uses of `--decorate-refs-exclude=<X>`, and could be overwritten somewhat with `--decorate-refs=refs/` and `--decorate-refs=HEAD`.
> However, it no longer becomes possible to include refs outside of the defaults while also excluding some using `log.excludeDecoration`.
>
> Another alternative would be to exclude the known namespaces that are not intended to be shown.
> This would reduce the visible effect of the change for expert users who use their own custom ref namespaces.
>
> It is critical that we provide ways for expert users to disable this behavior change via command-line options and config keys.

`git log` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/92156291ca82ae4f4ad09fde8181c5f2b7dba6ca/Documentation/git-log.txt#L54-L57):

> If none of these options or config settings are given, then references are
> used as decoration if they match `HEAD`, `refs/heads/`, `refs/remotes/`,
> `refs/stash/`, or `refs/tags/`.

And:

> ### [`log`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/748706d71365f419dad94cb7e54a31151c197218): add `--clear-decorations` option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The previous changes introduced a new default ref filter for decorations in the '[`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/748706d71365f419dad94cb7e54a31151c197218/Documentation/git-log.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> command.
> This can be overridden using `--decorate-refs=HEAD` and `--decorate-refs=refs/`, but that is cumbersome for users.
>
> Instead, add a `--clear-decorations` option that resets all previous filters to a blank filter that accepts all refs.

`git log` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/748706d71365f419dad94cb7e54a31151c197218/Documentation/git-log.txt#L59-L63):

> ### `--clear-decorations`
>
> When specified, this option clears all previous `--decorate-refs`
> or `--decorate-refs-exclude` options and relaxes the default
> decoration filter to include all references.

Example:

```
git log --decorate=full --pretty="tformat:%f%d" \
        --simplify-by-decoration \
        --decorate-refs-exclude="heads/octopus*" \
        --decorate-refs="heads" \
        --clear-decorations
```